# Compute the probability density function of Y

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $X \sim \mathrm{Uniform}(0, 1)$ random variable with the probability density function $f_X(x)$ given by
>   $$
> f_X(x) = \begin{cases} 1,  &0 < x < 1, \\ 0, &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
> $$
>   Let $Y$ = $\min\,\{X, 1 − X\}$. Compute the probability density function of $Y$.

So this $Y=\min\,\{X, 1-X\}$ confuses me. I'm not sure how to proceed.

When will $Y=X$ and $Y=1-X$ and how to consider these two cases?

Comment: When X<1/2:Y=X with probability P(X<1/2) =1/2 else Y=1-X with probability P(X>1/2) =1/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So this $Y=\min\{X,1−X\}$ confuses me. I'm not sure how to proceed.
>
> When will $Y=X$ and $Y=1−X$ and how to consider these two cases?

Consider that when the minimum of two variables is less than a value, then at least one from the variables is less than that value.   (Also the support for $Y$ will be $(0;1/2]$.) $$\begin{split}\mathsf P(Y\leq y)&=\mathsf P(\min\{X,1-X\}\leq y)~\mathbf 1_{y\in(0;1/2]}\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(X\leq y\cup 1-X\leq y)~\mathbf 1_{y\in(0;1/2]} \\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(X\leq y\cup X\geq 1-y)~\mathbf 1_{y\in(0;1/2]}\\[1ex] &~~\vdots\end{split}$$

The probability density function will be the unsigned differential of this cumulative distribution function.

Comment: why does y take values from 0 to 1/2?

Comment: @ThePoorJew Because $X$ takes values from 0 to 1, and so the minimum of $X,1-X$ will therefore be greater than 0 and at most 1/2.